# The Line-Break Thing

Tags: discussion, markdown

> How to Format
>   ► for linebreak add 2 spaces at end

Why?

Why can't Stack Overflow as one of the biggest "Coding-Platforms" handle a stupid "Line-Break" as a "Line-Break"? Why "2 Spaces at the end"?

Best,
[next line in editor view] dognose.

Comment: Thx for "-1" - But an answer or explanation would be so much more useful.

Comment: Well, that's not how markdown works, swallow or leave. (even presenting that as a code outline doesn't fit very well for what you're asking about)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ fixed the outline (sorry for that) - But what's the "real" background of this? "Swallow or leave" was for sure not the designers idea...?!

Comment: Fixed it more ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You're da real mvp

Comment: [_MVP_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_viable_product)??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_valuable_player

Comment: Usually not, I'm just  a mere mortal like most others around here, but THX for the flowers anyway :)

Comment: Comon guys i'm not "new" to SO - Please add some comments to your downvotes or *at least* explain why you think the question deserves downvotes!

Comment: _"Please add some comments to your downvotes ..."_ Disagreement this needs to be _discussed_ at Meta SO?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ If you "carefully" check the url, THIS IS meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @dognose: "*Please add some comments to your downvotes or at least explain why you think the question deserves downvotes!*" Because, at the end of the day, your question is clearly not a genuine search for the reason why SO uses this scheme. It's a *rant* disguised as a question, one which offers no justification for why the suggested method is an improvement over what we have now.

Comment: Related, but in a more civil manner: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26011/should-the-markdown-renderer-treat-a-single-line-break-as-br

Comment: I downvoted becasd;aoswerfpaowherft934yt034yrt39784r34fr

Comment: +1 as this post taught me how to do a soft break.. double-space. Who knew? Thanks!

Comment: I've never been able to get this to work - all my comments never have line breaks even when I press shift+return either with or without two spaces at the end of the line which I want to have a line break.

Answer (score 12):

I think the designers of [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/markdown) left us with the following choices:

1. Add a line-break to have your markdown code readable and maintainable
2. Add two spaces at the end, to have a soft line break, that will just add a newline to the rendered text.
3. Add a break and an extra empty line to start a new paragraph

Sounds like a pretty reasonable decision for me.

Comment: I understand (2) - which is nice. But why does (1) require *two spaces* at the end? - Why isn't it just a regular freaking linebereak?

Comment: Think twice, how to distinguish? I probably wasn't complete enough with my answer yet.

Comment: AFAIK, every code-post requires indentation - so every "regular" line break could be easily identified.

Comment: @dognose Sorry to invalidate your comment. It's referring to 3. now.

Comment: Okay, maybe it's just "cultural" difference? (I dont't know) - But Over here in Europe, Hitting "Enter / Return" means: "Switch to next line", But TBH: I never ever posted to any US-Forum where the meaning was any different...

Comment: @dognose _" But Over here in Europe ..."_ Did you check my profile?

Answer (score 12):

> Why can't stackoverflow as one of the biggest "Coding-Platforms" handle a stupid "Line-Break" as a "Line-Break"? Why "2 Spaces at the end"?

Here's a better question: why *should it?*

As far as plain text is concerned, double-spacing to have line breaks has been the way of things since the earliest text editors. Without paragraph indention, there's no other way to tell where one paragraph ends and another begins.

Markdown is a documentation format that is designed to be easily read regardless of whether it is formatted or not. Which means that, *by design*, it must use the standard way of depicting paragraph spacing: double-space.

Furthermore, it's often very useful to have line breaks inserted to prevent having to use wrapping or horizontal scrolling in your text editor. Breaking lines within a paragraph at, for example, 80 characters. If you respected all line breaks blindly when formatting that text, you would wreck your paragraph formatting.

Why go against that? Why develop a new dialect of Markdown (or worse, a whole new language) just for this? Why is what you propose in any way *better* than what we have now?